# WPF Application Installer language

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I have created an installer for my application WPF in Visual Studio 2015 in my project I have a folder called "language" containing two .resx files to change application language, but when creating the installer does not keep me these files because when I change the language button it does not make me change.

I need help for these files remain as when I run the application from Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

From Add --> Project output --> Localized resources and then is add every .resx file who you have in the project